# GIT - Push new files to old repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a project that we initially started locally and were pushing changes to BitBucket. When it came time to launch we launched, and since launch on the remote host server we have made some changes to the code remotely.

Now I would like to push all of those changes from the remote server to our repo. I have never once initialized Git on this remote system. So it's never been connected before.

I also don't want to harm our code on the server but I would like all of it to replace what is in the repo.

So how do I initialize without harming our server code then push everything to the repo replacing?

I would normally do this below, but I want to make sure I don't mess something up and I get everything since the code is already there and so is the repo:

```
git init
git remote add origin URL
git add -A .
git commit -m "Commit xxxx"
git push -u origin master
```

Is this still correct even though both place still have their own code?

Comment: You can init a repository, commit all your files, then add origin, fetch everything and rebase your new commit at the top of your master branch, then push. By doing a commit you won't lose anything, but you have to sync with your repository anyway.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do, is to put the changes on your remote server onto the master of your bitbucket repo.

You can do this as follows:

1. Clone the bitbucket repo on your remote server. Check out the master branch.
2. Copy over all the files in your remote server onto the clone directory.
3. Add all the changed files and add any new files that are not already in your bitbucket repo but are now in the cloned directory. Commit the changes.
4. Push the changes to bitbucket.

EDIT:

If do not want to copy over your bitbucket repo to the remote server, then the only thing you can do is to create a new branch in the newly initialised repo that does not yet exist on bitbucket, commit your remote server's version there and push it up to bitbucket, where you will get a separate version of the code.

However, you will still have two versions of the code on bitbucket - and have to manage them manually. If you replace the master branch on bitbucket with your server's version, you end up losing all the git commit history on the master branch.

*Note that, this approach will also end up copying 200 MB of your remote server's code to bitbucket. If you clone and then do it - like in the approach I suggested above, git will compute only the changes and then send those to bitbucket - the advantage being you will know what changed on your remote server, from the version in your bitbucket repo.*